# Xamarin - Specified cast not valid when loading collectionview. Page does not load and then the app crashes

Tags: xamarin.forms, casting, uicollectionview

I have a collection view and it should normally load all the object attributes but it crashes when opening the page:

```
public void Bind(object itemBindingContext, ItemsView itemsView,
           Action<Size> reportMeasure = null, Size? size = null)
       {
           var template = _template.SelectDataTemplate(itemBindingContext, itemsView);

           var templateChanging = template != _selectedTemplate;

           if (templateChanging)
           {
               // Clean up any content we're still holding on to
               _itemContentView.Recycle();

               // Create the new content
               View = (View)template.CreateContent();

               // Set the binding context _before_ we create the renderer; that way, the bound data will be 
               // available during OnElementChanged
               View.BindingContext = itemBindingContext;

               // Make sure the Visual property is available when the renderer is created
               PropertyPropagationExtensions.PropagatePropertyChanged(null, View, itemsView);

               // Actually create the native renderer
               _itemContentView.RealizeContent(View);

               _selectedTemplate = template;
           }

           _itemContentView.HandleItemSizingStrategy(reportMeasure, size);

           if (!templateChanging)
           {
               // Same template, new data
               View.BindingContext = itemBindingContext;
           }

           itemsView.AddLogicalChild(View);
       }
```

It crashes at this line: `View = (View)template.CreateContent();`

This is the collection view:

```
<CollectionView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                                Margin="0,10,20,0" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Libraries}"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                HeightRequest="210">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Margin="8,0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <sh:Shadows Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                Shades="{sh:SingleShade Opacity=0.4, BlurRadius=10, Color=Black}"  CornerRadius="100">
                                        <Frame Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#D9D9D9" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" CornerRadius="100" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                            <Image x:Name="userImage"  Source="{Binding Picture, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageConverter}}" WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=100, Android=100}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </sh:Shadows>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue='Sconosciuto'}" FontFamily="Inter" FontAttributes="Bold" MaxLines="3" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Address, TargetNullValue='Sconosciuto'}"  FontFamily="Inter" FontSize="13" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

This is how I load the collectionview 'Libraries' in the viewmodel:

```
public LoanBookPageViewModel(Book book) {
            Book = book;
            Libraries = BookService.GetLibrariesWithAvailableBook(Book);
        }
```

Libraries is correctly filled with objects so that's not the problem.

Comment: ViewCell is only used in ListView, not CollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if we add a `ViewCell` element inside of `CollectionView`, the following error will be thrown.

```
 System.InvalidCastException:`Special cast is not valid`
```

So, try to remove the element `ViewCell` inside of your `CollectionView`.

And just as Jason mentioned, element `ViewCell` will be needed in `ListView`.

For example:

```
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items }">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```